# Spatial join based on a categorising attribute

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I have two shapefiles that I want to spatial join (closest match), however, in the second shapefile I have records that are split by attribute X.  
I want the closest to records from each unique X record to shapefile nodes. i.e. the closest match usually pick the closest record from shapefile 2 to shapefile 1 nodes, but I want the closest from each X attribute value to each of shapefile 1 nodes.

An example would be:
Shapefile 1: different schools around the city.
Shapefile 2: Kids around the city Attribute X: Age category (1,2,3).
I want the closest kid from each age category to every school.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

This example, using QGIS, requires four steps to go...

Before starting, please download and install [refFunctions](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin.

[image]

Provided we have an example of three schools and nine children dataset like below:

- `school_layer`: **id** (1,2,...) and **school_id** (School_A, ...)
- `kids_layer`: **id** (1,2,...), **kids_id** (a, b, ...) and **kid_age** (1, 2, ...)

(1) Split `kids_layer` into three sublayers according to their age group.

`QGIS Processing Toolbox | QGIS | Vector general tools | Split vector layer`

[image]

I chose \GIS\temp\kids folder to save sublayers, but any place is fine.

(2) Load the sublayers (~.shp) into QGIS.

[image]

(3) Open the attribute table of `school_layer` and create a new field (**age_1**), by the following expression:

```
geomnearest('kids_layer_kid_age_1', 'kids_id')
```

[image]

(4) Repeat the above (3) for **age_2** and **age_3**, too.

```
[age_2]field:  geomnearest('kids_layer_kid_age_2', 'kids_id')
[age_3]field:  geomnearest('kids_layer_kid_age_3', 'kids_id')
```

[image]

Your `school_layer`'s attribute table will become like above.

As can be seen on the topmost picture, School_A is closest to **a** (Age 1= ping group), **b** (Age 2= green group) and **i** (Age 3= blue group).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this actually works perfectly, however the issue here is that if the number of categories is higher than 3, (I have a case where I have 880 categories; not age categories of course but different categories) then it would be really painful to have 880 shapefiles and then repeating step 3 for 880 times! 
Are you aware of anyway around this? 

Many thanks

Comment: @Mahmoud It seems your core part of your question. Will you edit and include that information in your post? Somebody can pick it up and offer you a solution. Thanks!